# ExtJs - How to remove all floating components

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Using ExtJs 4.1

Is there a way to query all **floating** components (windows, message boxes, etc.)?

My aim is to remove (destroy) all floating objects. It would be sufficient to "get" them on the first hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well simply do it by using the **[Ext.WindowManager](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.WindowManager)** which is responsible for all floating components by default.

Following should work:

```
Ext.WindowManager.each(function(cmp) { cmp.destroy(); });
```

Here's a example **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aZy9/)**:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {  // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
        xtype: 'grid',
        border: false,
        columns: [{header: 'World'}],                 // One header just for show. There's no data,
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {}) // A dummy empty data store
    }
}).show();

Ext.Function.defer(function(){Ext.WindowManager.each(function(cmp) { cmp.destroy(); })}, 5000);
```

For further reading on **[DOM-Query](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/#selectors)**

**Edit** *destroy only defined types*

For that case go with the xtype of the component and check it.

```
Ext.WindowManager.each(function(cmp) { if (cmp.xtype === 'window') cmp.destroy(); });
```

Comment: Thanks again for your fast answers! Works perfectly. Would be something like this somehow possible: `Ext.dom.query('id[class*=messagebox]')`

Comment: @Indianer No ,because Id is no valid HTML element. Here's a valid example: `Ext.dom.query('div[class*=messagebox]')`

Comment: Thanks. Another question on `Ext.WindowManager`. How do I check for the component type? Let's say in my `each` function I want only to hide all messageboxes?

Comment: Thanks also found `getXType()`

Comment: @Indianer See my edit. I guess hide is not be that hard, isn't it? Just remove `destroy()` with `hide()`

Comment: @Indianer If possible spare function calls in loops. Ok then, I guess by know this question should be answered, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Yes it is. I will use the function since there is no xtype prop at a messagebox cmp.

Comment: @Indianer No, you are wrong, there is. see **[Ext.window.MessageBox](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox)**

Comment: Ok but in my console there was none. Another question, how do I programmatically fire the "Yes" or "Cancel" button of a messagebox? Like in my `each` function say `cmp.confirm()`

Comment: This works to fire the OK button: `oCmp.msgButtons[0].fireHandler();` is there a better way?

Comment: @Indianer Yes, by using a ComponentQuery you didn't need to know the index of the button. And note that for example the Chrome console not shows some inherited or mixed-in members.